# Finding the text of a element when some of it is highlighted

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to make sure that the string I have searched is highlighted in the div, as sometimes it doesn't highlight all that I search for.
The problem is, when it is highlighted I can't find it with

```
'//div[contains(text(), "' + text + '")]'
```

as the element is split.

Example of an highlighted element:

```
<span _ngcontent -c58 class="cli">
<span class="yellow-highlight">12</span>
"34567"
</span>
```

With the example, if I try to find "123" I won't find it as it doesn't contain that exact text.

Ideas?

**UPDATE:

Ended up creating 2 lists, one is made of "yellow-highlight" elements and one is just with the original text.
If the size weren't a match I figured there must be a problem and the highlight didn't go as planned.
Thanks :)

Comment: You look for `div` but we can see `span` in the HTML

Comment: Rafal, my point was I can't find using that way, regardless of "div" or "span".
Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this,

```
driver.findElement(By.XPath("*//span[normalize-space(contains(text(),'123'))]"))
```

Answer (score 1):

xpath

> //div[normalize-space(contains(text(), '123'))]